# ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (50, 11)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:
[image]

and is generated by using panda:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\amlut\\Desktop\\Classes\\Case Studies\\SureFactor_Demand.xlsx")
df = df.dropna()
df.columns = ["Week", "DemandB15", "Demand C17", "Demand D20", "Demand D25", "Demand E26", "Demand F35"]
df.iloc[1,0] = 1
df = df.iloc[1:51]
df.index = range(0,50)
```

trying to run `ols` on this dataframe `result = ols(formula = "DemandB15 ~ Week", data=df).fit()` generates the error:

```
ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (50, 11). This occurs when the variable converted to endog is non-numeric (e.g., bool or str).
```

There does not appear to be any non-numerics in my dataframe, so I am very confused on this error. I have very little experience with python or panda, so please assume the knowledge of an absolute noob.

Comment: can you try dtype option when to call ```read_excel```. [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)   ```dtype={'DemandB15': 'int32', 'DemandC17': 'int32', ....}```

Comment: I am getting the same ValueError and do not have any non-numeric columns in data as well.